# Re-define File::dirname ruby method

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to redefine the File.dirname method to first change %20s to spaces.  But the following gives me an error

```
class File
   old_dirname = instance_method(:dirname)    

   define_method(:dirname) { |s|
       s = s.gsub("%20"," ")
       old_dirname.bind(self).call(s)
   }
end
```

This trhows a NameError exception: undefined method 'dirname' for class 'File'

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Chuck already wrote, `File::dirname` is a singleton method of the `File` class object (or more precisely an instance method of the `File` class object's metaclass), not an instance method of the `File` class.

So, you have to open up `File`'s metaclass, not the `File` class itself:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

class << File
  old_dirname = instance_method :dirname

  define_method :dirname do |*args|
    old_dirname.bind(self).(*args).gsub '%20', ' '
  end
end

require 'test/unit'
class TestFileDirname < Test::Unit::TestCase
  def test_that_it_converts_percent20_to_space
    assert_equal '/foo bar/baz', File.dirname('/foo%20bar/baz/quux.txt')
  end
end
```

However, I agree with @sheldonh: this breaks the API contract of `File::dirname`.

Answer (score 3):

Just be careful.

You're changing the behaviour of the method, not just its implementation.  This is generally poor practice, because it weakens the value of the API as a dependable contract.

Instead, consider transforming the input closer to the point of receipt.

Answer (score 1):

`dirname` is a class method of File, not an instance method, so you're just defining a new instance method. Also, the idiomatic way to alias a method is with `alias`. So:

```
class <<File
  alias old_dirname dirname
  def dirname(f)
    old_dirname(f.gsub("%20", " "))
  end
end
```

The `class <<whatever` syntax adds methods to an individual object — in this case, the File class.

Comment: This is *not* equivalent to the code @jrhicks posted in his question! This code pollutes the `File` metaclass's namespace with a residual `File::old_dirname` method, whereas the original code in the question takes great care to avoid this issue.

Comment: The discussion of scope is entirely correct, Chuck, but Jörg is right: `alias_method` may be "idiomatic," but it's definitely less safe than the OP's original approach.